# Why the loops are avoided in Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I read Kruskal's algorithm as it's presented on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). There, it says that it's an algorithm in graph theory that finds a minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted graph.

But while going through the [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Example) that illustrate this algorithm I am unable to understand why the *loops are avoided* by marking some of the edges in red.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I think this belongs on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please do not crosspost: we can migrate questions to the right place if you post it on the wrong site. For lack of a better site, non-research-level help with algorithms is on-topic here on Programmers; CSTheory.SE is for research-level theoretical questions. There's a site proposal in the works, [Computer Science (Non-Programming)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=RaYobbitpqczXN85c5ibxQ2), that's supposed to bridge the gap between SO/Programmers and CSTheory.

Answer (score 3):

Kruskal's algorithm, gives a minimum spanning *tree*, and a tree does not have any cycles (loops). So the algorithm should avoid construction of loops in finding the minimum spanning subgraph.

Answer (score 0):

You must already know that you cannot have cycles in a tree. So while adding any edge to the MST you must make sure that no loop or cycle is being created .
Secondly in the example that you posted , red color is only used to clarify that this particular link should not be added to the MST as it will create a loop. So loops are not avoided by making some of the edges red rather loops are avoided by not adding the edges that connect the already connected vertices ( for example B and D in step 5 of the example mentioned by you) and such links are shown in red to avoid confusion